# Duplicated contacts in Outlook

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook, contacts

I have some issues related to MS Outlook and contacts. I use MS Outlook 2007 where I have my personal mailbox and a shared mailbox, both in Exchange.
I have checked the "Check for duplicate contacts" checkbox in the contacts options, but it doesn't work well:

When I paste existing contacts in the shared mailbox, Outlook don´t show the "Duplicated Contact" warning in a lot of them, so they are duplicated. It always happen with the same contacts.

When I paste the same existing contacts in my personal mailbox, Outlook show the "Duplicated Contact" warning except in a few of them. It always happen with the same contacts.

I have tried with other versions of Outlook with the same results.

Anybody knows why doesn´t work the contact duplication detection?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a duplicate contact, and Outlook will allow this. Please go through this link of [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Resolve-or-delete-duplicate-contacts-0fa9c0a0-499a-48ab-b818-4e6463ccb9fa) and you will know how to handle with duplicate contacts.

Thank you.